# Generate sitemap according prismic data in Nuxt

Tags: module, nuxt.js, sitemap, prismic.io

I'm guessing some of you have some experience with generating Sitemap for your project.
I'm having a Nuxt ( SSR full static ) project.
I'm using [@nuxtjs/prismic](https://prismic.nuxtjs.org/)
and [@nuxtjs/sitemap module](https://sitemap.nuxtjs.org/).

The sitemap module does not generate dynamic pages therefor we need to asynchronously retrieve all the pages we have on the website and process the data into a format required by the sitemap module.

I'm guessing that I need to write some build module where I would have access to prismic and then generate and write the desired data format.

Help me please to understand how to import or access prismic from module level so I can write the desired logic.

**UPDATE**
I created build module and registered it in nuxt.config.js.
Successfully retrieving data from prismic query. In the code bellow In my loop I transform prismic data in to data format that is required by the sitemap module.

I pass the data to sitemap module with `this.nuxt`.
Right now this code passes the correct data however the module overrides the static pages and the only correct data left is for the dynamic pages. It looks that I need to disable the automatic generate by the module and only to work with my data.

```js
// ... all dynamic pages generated correctly
<url>
<loc>https://danica-dev.netlify.app/blog/arrival-of-ikea-in-ukraine</loc>
<lastmod>2021-05-01T14:00:04.000Z</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.3</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>https://danica-dev.netlify.app/en</loc>
</url>
<url>
<loc>https://danica-dev.netlify.app/kontakt</loc>
</url>
<url>
<loc>https://danica-dev.netlify.app/privacy-policy</loc>
</url>
<url>
<loc>https://danica-dev.netlify.app/ru</loc>
</url>
<url>
<loc>https://danica-dev.netlify.app/en/blog</loc>
</url>
<url>
<loc>https://danica-dev.netlify.app/en/contact</loc>
</url>
<url>
<loc>https://danica-dev.netlify.app/en/privacy-policy</loc>
</url>
<url>
<loc>https://danica-dev.netlify.app/en/projects</loc>
</url>
<url>
<loc>https://danica-dev.netlify.app/ru/blog</loc>
</url>
<url>
<loc>https://danica-dev.netlify.app/ru/kontakt</loc>
</url>
<url>
<loc>https://danica-dev.netlify.app/ru/privacy-policy</loc>
</url>
<url>
<loc>https://danica-dev.netlify.app/ru/projects</loc>
</url>
```

```js
// modules/sitemap.js
import prismic from '@prismicio/client'

const apiEndpoint = 'https://danica.cdn.prismic.io/api/v2'
const client = prismic.client(apiEndpoint)

export default async function Sitemap() {
    const data = await client.query('', { pageSize: 100 })
    const pages = []

    data.results.forEach((page) => {
        switch (page.type) {
            case 'blog_post':
                pages.push({
                    url: `blog/${page.uid}`,
                    changefreq: 'weekly',
                    priority: 0.25,
                    lastmod: page.last_publication_date,
                })
                break
            case 'project_post':
                pages.push({
                    url: `projects/${page.uid}`,
                    changefreq: 'monthly',
                    priority: 0.5,
                    lastmod: page.last_publication_date,
                })
                break
      //...
            default:
                break
        }
    })

    this.nuxt.options.sitemap.routes = pages
}
```

Comment: What did you tried so far? We're here to help you with a technical issue, not for a tutorial as to say.

Comment: Hi @kissu, thanks for your time, I updated my post. I hope it helps to understand the situation better

Comment: Should it be `sitemap` rather than `Sitemap`? Also, shouldn't you return an array at the end? Is it empty?

Comment: I loop trough the array of data.results where I transform prismic data in to data format required by the sitemap module.
Then with this.nuxt I try to pass the array to the sitemap module

Comment: Do you have what is expected in the final array?

Comment: yes i do, but it seems that I do not know to pass it properly to the sitemap module